# Cannot access workspace of the user in new server when trying to shift the TFS server to another PC

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, disaster-recovery

We are using TFS 2012. All the PC are connected by using Workgroup.(we are not using domain). The TFS PC is having PC name as PCTFS . We have about 15 developers who use TFS. As we use workgroup so we have created all windows users of 15 developers in the TFS server pc. So now TFS server PC has windows users like PCTFS\user1 , PCTFS\user2 ,PCTFS\user3 so on.

All these users connect to TFS server PC from their PC. As they have same user created in TFS server PC the authentication works by matching windows user name. So developer can connect to TFS server and work on it.  Each user has its own permissions like create workspace , shelveset, chekin permission etc.

When trying to shift the TFS server to another PC. So PC name having TFS installed will change from PCTFS to PCNEWTFS . So when After restoring the sql databases of all collection.

So , First we remapped using : 
TFSConfig RemapDBs /DatabaseName:PCNEWTFS\SQLEXPRESS;TFS_Configuration /SQLInstances:PCNEWTFS\SQLEXPRESS

Then we reset the owner  using :

```
TFSConfig Accounts /ResetOwner /SQLInstance: PCNEWTFS \SQLEXPRESS /DatabaseName:TFS_Configuration
```

Then we added  the account  using :

```
TfsConfig Accounts /add /AccountType:ApplicationTier /account: PCNEWTFS \user1 
/SQLInstance: PCNEWTFS \SQLEXPRESS /DatabaseName:Tfs_Configuration
```

At last we changed the identities using :

```
TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain: PCTFS /todomain: PCNEWTFS
```

All the operation were successful and all the newely created users are accessible after changing identities.

Like ,

```
   Account name                          Exists                  Matches 

   PCNEWTFS\user1                        True                    False
```

Please help me in the following questions

We referred the following [article](http://mscop.be.capgemini.com/2011/03/06/team-foundation-server-disaster-recovery-part-one/) .

When trying  to access workspace of the user in new server all the workspaces are referring to old server  they are not shifted to new server. How to make them refer new server  ?

**Edit:**
We have shifted tfs server from PC110 to PC78 by using the steps mentioned above.
In the screenshoot below you can see that all the workspaces are still referring to old server (PC110) instead of PC78 (new server)

What are the necessary steps to be followed to make the workspace to refer new server during disaster recovery ?(We can manually transfer our workspace of each user of using command or altering the database tables but it is not the best method when there is many no of users)

Are we missing any steps in disaster recovery plan which makes workspaces still refer old server?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have everything right. Workspaces should move across automatically but I have no experience with non domain intances of TFS.